# PreferenceFragmentCompat not showing all preference from XML

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-settings

I am setting up `PreferenceScreen` on my app but `PreferenceFragmentCompat` not showing all mentioned XML preference on screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        android:key="app_setting"
        android:summary="General account setting for app"
        android:title="Account Setting">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:checked="true"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check"
            android:key="button"
            android:summary="Turn on "
            android:switchTextOff="OFF"
            android:switchTextOn="ON"
            android:title="Updates" />

        <Preference
            android:fragment="com.reacher.Settings_Fragmets.BackUp_Fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_loop_black_24dp"
            android:summary="Reset your account by deleting all data from server and from app excluding users connections"
            android:title="Reset Account" />


    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_vibration_black_24dp"
            android:key="Notification_vibrate"
            android:summary="Vibrate when receive new notification"
            android:title="Vibrate" />



    </PreferenceCategory>


    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Privacy &amp; User Setting">
        <Preference
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_backup_black_24dp"
            android:key="bkup"
            android:summary="Backup"
            android:title="Account">

        </Preference>

        <Preference
            android:key="blocked"
            android:summary="People's you block to view your profile and send you message"
            android:title="Blocked List">

        </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>
                              


                         <!--NOT SHOWING ANY PREFERENCE FROM HERE -->

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_phonelink_lock_black_24dp"
        android:title="Control">

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:dialogTitle="Post"
            android:entries="@array/pref_futurepost_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_futurepost_values"
            android:key="futurePot"
            android:summary=" next post."
            android:title="Future Post">

        </ListPreference>
      
        
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:dialogTitle="Allow Comments"
            android:entries="@array/pref_futurepost_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_futurepost_values"
            android:key="Post"
            android:title="Post">

        </ListPreference>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="dob"
            android:summary="Check"
            android:title="chk parent " />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="email"
            android:title="Allow 0 " />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="distance"
            android:title="Allow 1" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="status"
            android:title="Allow 2 " />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="directMessage"
            android:title="Allow 3" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Server tester">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="Email"
            android:title="test 0" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="Ph"
            android:title="test 1" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="loc"
            android:title="test 2" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
                     



                            <!--NOT SHOWING ANY PREFERENCE TO HERE -->


    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Developer(BETA)">

        <Preference
            android:summary="Develop your plugins and publish it as add-on"
            android:title="Register" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Inflating/Loading preference in `PreferenceFragmentCompat` at `onCreatePreferences`

```
` @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        //Load The preferences from xml
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting_main,rootKey);
}`
```

why i am not able to see all preferences on my fragment.any ideas ?

Comment: Probably you need to scroll up the preference screen to see them

Comment: @Zain Only some are showing but as i mentioned in question (XML) those are not visible

Comment: Yes I know I just guess that you see the top `PreferenceCategory`s when you launch the app, and you need to scroll up the preference list to see the rest of them

Comment: @Zain is that solution? :)

Comment: @androidXP that is why it is a comment 

Answer (score 0):

> why i am not able to see all preferences on my fragment.any ideas ?

Well, one thing that looks wrong is you're passing some variable `rootKey` for the root preference screen ...

```
setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting_main,rootKey);
```

But your layout doesn't have a key specified:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

Either pass `null` or set the same string `"key"=YOUR_STRING` in the XML.

Comment: rootkey is default key. please check updated question

Comment: OK ... did you try my suggestions?

Comment: yes i did and i end up setting up programmatically